# Question about how to get the residue for infinite amount of poles

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

So I am asked to find the residue for each pole such as 
$$
f(z) = \frac{z}{1-\cos(2z)} 
$$
I understand pole of order 2 with $z= 2\pi k$ excluding zero.

I also understand that residue equals to cauchy integral over the curve with integrand f(z)

I am not sure how to apply it because I am not given the radius and

only used to using short cut formula for residue and simple poles.

From my understanding I know the generalized cauchy formula with denominator of integrand

of power of $(k+1)$ derives $f^{(k)}(z_0)$ and I also know that when there is pole of order two you

can get the residue right away by evaluating the holomorphic function inside the integrand

and multiply $\pi/2$ but this is infinite amount of poles so I am not sure how I could

do this. Can someone explain me why integral over the curve of f(z) is residue?

I mean integral over entirely analytic function on domain D is 0 and residue therefore

equals 0 but this is all the knowledge I know.

Comment: Do I parametrize this respect to theta?

Comment: What is the order of each pole?

Comment: second order...

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how to apply it because I am not given the radius and

It doesn't matter as long as there's **only one** singularity enclosed by the curve.

> Can someone explain me why integral over the curve of f(z) is residue?

I don't think I understand this question. This is just a definition.

There are some easier ways to calculate residues when the singularity is a pole. If $z_0$ is a pole of order $n$ of $f$, then:
$$
\operatorname{res}_{z_0}f = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z\to z_0}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\right)^{n-1} ((z-z_0)^nf(z))
$$

Answer (score 1):

The poles are all multiples of $\pi$, not $2\pi$, and $0$ is included.

Hint: if $z =  \pi k + t$, $1 - \cos(2z) = 2 t^2 + \ldots$.

You almost never compute a residue by actually integrating.

Answer (score 1):

We want to calculate:

\begin{align}
 \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = n\pi}\left(\frac{z}{1-\cos(2z)}\right)
\end{align}

For the case $n=0$, we use the Maclaurin series of $\cos(x)$:
\begin{align}
\frac{z}{1-\cos(2z)} &= \frac{z}{1-(1-z^2/2!+z^4/4!-z^6/6!\ldots)}\\
                     &= \frac{z}{z^2/2!-z^4/4!+z^6/6!\ldots}\\
                     &= \frac{z}{2z^2(1-2z^2/4!+2z^4/6!+\ldots)}\\
                     &= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z(1-2z^2/4!+2z^4/6!+\ldots)}
\end{align}

At this point you can use Cauchy's integral formula with $ f=\frac{1}{1-2z^2/4!+2z^4/6!+\ldots}$

\begin{align}
 \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = 0}\left(\frac{z}{1-\cos(2z)}\right) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

For the case $n\neq0$, we use the subsitution $w=z-n\pi$ and take the residue at $w=0$ (i.e. $z=n\pi$):

\begin{align}
\frac{z}{1-\cos(2z)} &= \frac{w+n\pi}{1-\cos(2w+2n\pi)}\\
                     &= \frac{w+n\pi}{1-\cos(2w)}\\
                     &= \frac{w}{1-\cos(2w)} + \frac{n\pi}{1-\cos(2w)}\\\\
\end{align}
Here we can use again Maclaurin series and Cauchy's integral formula, but using our previous result:
The first term is (as before) $1$.
The second term has a pole of 2nd order at $w=0$, hence its residue equals $0$.

Finally we have:

\begin{align}
 \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = n\pi}\left(\frac{z}{1-\cos(2z)}\right) &= \frac{1}{2}\quad
\end{align}

I think this is an easy way to calculate the residues.
Otherwise, you should calculate the Laurent series at every $z=n\pi$.

About the radius of convergence, the Laurent series at $z=n\pi$ have a radius of convergence $r<\pi$, so that it "won't touch the next pole".